# New way of jquery object creation

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code has this line.

```
var variableName = $("<div class='class-name'></div>");
console.log(variableName); -> Object[div.class-name]
```

I wanted to know what does this refers to in Jquery and how we can add move values in that object like

```
Object[div.class-name, div.class-name]
```

The actual Code is :

```
    var overlapCollector;
    $.each(region, function(i, r){
      var overlapper = $("<div class='markup-overlapper'></div>").appendTo( markupCanvas );
      overlapper.css({
          "position": "absolute",
          "left": r.x1,
          "top": r.y1,
          "width": r.x2-r.x1,
          "height": r.y2-r.y1
      }).toggleClass("exclude", ex);
      overlapCollector = overlapper.add(overlapper);
      console.log(overlapCollector);
  });
```

Please help

Thanks

Comment: You can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/).

Comment: Tried, but failed. :(

Comment: You need to put it first in a variable and assign it. Check my answer.

Comment: `.add()` returns a new jQuery object.  jQuery itself does not support a straightforward method for adding to the current jQuery object.  Because of the way various methods work on jQuery objects, they are generally not designed to be modified once created.  Methods that filter or add, etc... typically return new jQuery objects with the modifications applied.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use .add() but you also have to remember that this function does not append to the current object, but returns a new object containing what you want.

the appropriate behavior will be ensured by using:

```
var variableName = $("<div class='class-name'></div>");
variableName = variableName.add($("<div class='another-div'></div>"));
console.log(variableName); -> Object[div.class-name, div.another-div]
```

EDIT: Since the comment below asked about looping:

```
var variableName = $("<div class='class-name'></div>");
for(...){
    variableName = variableName.add($("<div class='another-div'></div>"));
}
console.log(variableName); -> Object[div.class-name, div.another-div, ..., div.another-div]
```

Comment: Thanks @Corvus, I think this doesn't work in loop right ?

Comment: it would, yes, as long as variableName is outside of the scope of the loop, then you are just doing an append and replace operation each iteration.

Comment: code is edited above, I wanted variable ovarlapCollector to have all the div inside as Object[div.markup-overlapper, div.markup-overlapper, ...]

Comment: This is becoming out of the scope of this question and is becoming more related to overall code structure. For this I would suggest thinking a bit more about what you want to accomplish and if using .add is even going to achieve this. it is sounding more like you just want to iterate over something and append() to the markupCanvas it rather than make another container just for the sake of using add()

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to create a new jQuery object with elements added to the set of matched elements. It **returns** the set of matches as a **new** jQuery object.

So your code might look like:

```js
var variableName = $("<div class='class-name'></div>");
variableName = variableName.add($("<span class='new-class'></span>"));
console.log(variableName); // -> Object[div.class-name, span.new-class]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

`$("<div class='class-name'></div><div class='class-name'></div>")`

or this

`$("<div class='class-name'></div>").add("<div class='class-name'></div>")`

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you mean by "creating move (more?) values in that object".

If you are referring to attributes, you can do:

```
var x = $('<div/>', {"class":"class-name", "id":"someId"});
```

If you are wanting to add another object to your current collection, you'll need to use .add() (as mentioned):

```
var x = $('<div/>');
x.add('div');
```

here you will end up with 2 divs in your "collection". Also, the jQuery object collection will return in the order that the elements appear in the DOM - not in the order you may have added to the collection....

HTH

Comment: Glad to have ideally helped - you can always tick as correct answer and/or upvote :)

Comment: Unsure if naive or spent too long looking at reddit